# Product Url with subcategories

Tags: magento

How can I get product Url with sub-categories Path link ?

Comment: I tried fixing the grammar, but I still can't understand what this means

Answer (score 0):

[Magento: externally get relative URL's to categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068535/magento-externally-get-relative-urls-to-categories)

Answer (score 0):

use magento object to get product's information
example:
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
echo $product->getProductUrl();

Answer (score 0):

you can get product url through
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getProductCollection()->getFirstItem();
    return $product_collection->getProductUrl();